# Given a Jacobian, can we calculate the corresponding vector field?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, matrix-calculus, jacobian

Suppose we find, somewhere in the wild, a Jacobian matrix $J(x)$ (so, $J_{i,j}=\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$). Let us assume the matrix function is square and continuous and maps to a real space of square matrices. Can we then always find the corresponding vector field $f$?

And the follow-up question would be, given any square ($n\times n$) and continuous matrix function $K(x)$ (with $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$), can we always see this as a Jacobian, and find a function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\frac{\partial g (x)}{\partial x}=K(x)$?

Comment: Of course 
$$f(x) - f(x_0) = \int_{x_0}^{x} J(z)\cdot dz$$
but not all functions _closed-form_ integrals

Comment: Does this also hold for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, so $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$? This was the part I was not sure about

Comment: The differential form of the equation is definitely true, i.e. $$df=J\cdot dx$$ However the integral form above is only true if the RHS is _path-independent_

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, when you are given a matrix function $J$, then there always exists at least one (implicit) function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\frac{df}{dx}(x) = J(x)$?